# remove conversation id from url in weld conversationScoped

Tags: java, java-ee-6, cdi, weld

Can I hide Conversation id(cid) from url in my poroject.I use weld and my ManagedBean Are ConversationScoped.how can hide queryString from end of my url.

Comment: Why do you need this? URL bookmarks?

Comment: i want pass my parametr(cid) but dont show it in url.i dont need bookmarks.can i handle it with prettyfaces or url-rewriting?

Answer (score -1):

You can't, the container will lose the conversation state and create a new inactive conversation if you remove the `cid` parameter.

Comment: are there any way to post this data?

Comment: According to this, http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html#d0e1777, the conversation scope fully supports the POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern, but I'm not sure if this would actually remove the parameter.

Comment: Hasan is just asking about how to rewrite the url. it is definitely possible with rewriting. you are just confusing him.